# react-select-event doesn't trigger the onChange function to set the value during testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-select

It's been a couple of days that I'm struggling with a test I'm trying to write and thought this would be a good place to ask for some tips. I'm trying to fill a form that uses `react-select` dropdowns, and these forms are inside a map that renders 4 of them. However when trying to run the code below on the selectors of each form in a loop, after the first iteration which runs fine, the input element found in the form to perform the onChange doesn't have the onChange handler and doesn't trigger the change function to select the option I need. The package I am using for the selection is `react-select-event` as per the documentation [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-react-select-event/). I am still a beginner with `react-testing-library` and testing in general so it's quite probable that I missed something. Any tips or ideas are welcome! Thank you

```
const selectOptionAndAssertValue = async (indicator, field, element, option, inputForm) => {
  await selectEvent.select(element, option.label, {
    container: document.body,
  });

  await waitFor(
    async () => {
      expect(inputForm).toHaveFormValues({
        [${indicator.short_alias}-${field}]: option.value,
      });
    },
    {
      onTimeout: error => console.log(error),
    }
  );
};
```

Note: to find the inputForm, I am using findByLabelText and it does find the  element.

---

EDIT: Issue replicated in this repo https://github.com/ildaballiu/select-testing-demo

---

Comment: Could you please provide the full code of your test, and the code for the component under test as well?

Comment: @juliomalves I can't provide the whole code as it's a quite large component, but this [repo here](https://github.com/ildaballiu/select-testing-demo) replicates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by changing the container to

```
 container: () => document.body.querySelector('[class$=-menu]')
```